# отладка на физическом устройстве через WiFi

Tags: android, ubuntu, android-studio

Вопрос довольно странный:

Использую ubuntu 14.04 и хочу сделать отладку на смартфоне. Но не через usb - кабель, а через **WiFi**.

**Возможно сделать это?**

**Если да, то как ?**

Comment: на счёт Wi-Fi не знаю, но pdanet, вроде, позволяла запускать приложение через bluetooth

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, если есть какое-то руководство  - порошу кинуть мне

Comment: Кроме [этого](http://4pda.ru/forum/index.php?showtopic=138332) ничего не нашёл.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Возможно. В официальных [доках](https://developer.android.com/intl/ru/tools/help/adb.html#wireless) есть информация.

1. Подключите устройство и компьютер к одной и той же сети.
2. Приконектиться по USB.
3. Установите прослушку на TCP/IP и порт 5555.

   `$ adb tcpip 5555`
4. Отключите USB.
5. Найдите IP адрес девайса. К примеру, на Нексусах вы можете найти IP в Settings > About tablet (or About phone) > Status > IP address.
6. Присоединитесь к этому девайсу `adb connect <device-ip-address>`.
7. Подтвердите:

   `$ adb devices
   List of devices attached
   <device-ip-address>:5555 device`

Вот и всё.

Answer (score 4):

Делаю так:

1. устанавливаю какой-нибудь ADB  manager. можно [ADB Manager](https://f-droid.org/repository/browse/?fdfilter=adb&fdid=com.matoski.adbm) или
   [adbWireless](https://f-droid.org/repository/browse/?fdfilter=adb&fdid=siir.es.adbWireless)
2. запускаем, менеджер говорит что-то типа
   ip_address:port
3. дальше в консоли компьютера `adb connect ip_address:port`

PS. Все ADB менеджеры которые видел требуют вай фай, подправил у удного из них код, и теперь можно такимже образом отлаживать в android-x86 на VMWare или VirtualBox (по ethernet соединению)

Comment: Кстати, не знаю как для AndroidStudio, для Eclipse есть даже плагин ADB Connect, что бы пропустить шаг 3