# Не могу подключить отладку к телефону, через wi fi

Tags: android, отладка, wifi, tcp-ip, adb

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не могу подключиться к телефону через wi fi, вот по этой инструкции https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb

Comment: Учтите что эти действия нужно выполнять по кабелю USB. Так же не забудьте включить отладку по USB

Comment: отладка по usb включена

Comment: Нужно подключить телефон через кабель.

Comment: телефон подключен через кабель

Comment: Что-то `ip` не похож на локальный - телефон и ПК должны быть в одной сети, через глобальную паутину подключиться нельзя. Попробуйте ещё раз по этому ответу: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/494441/11515

Comment: делала все тоже самое, работает на другом телефоне, а на моем huawei нет